# Angular 2 - Web and mobile

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I´m developing a platform that will be deployed on web and mobile. Currently I am developing the web part using Angular 2 and bootstrap, the next step will be to use Ionic or nativscript to make the mobile part. 
Considering that the view logic will be the same, and only will change the templates, which it is the best way to manage this 2 projects? Thinking on maintenance, and trying to not duplicate the code. 
Thanks!

Comment: Actually, your view models could be subjected to change also. The usual method of abstracting the core logic to classes should be enough to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good solution for this problem in this link: http://angularjs.blogspot.com.uy/2016/03/code-reuse-in-angular-2-native-mobile.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use KendoUI together with NativeScript both for Angular 2:
https://www.nativescript.org/blog/angular-2-web-and-mobile-demo-app-using-kendo-ui-and-nativescript

Single project with shared bootstrap and code between web and native.